# Modifying and validating fields in a DataTable c#

Tags: c#

I have the following datatable:

[image: Data from myDDBB]

the field "court_case" has a different format and is not compact, the expected format would be: XXXX/XX ("4 digits" / "2 digits" )

For example:

```
12/13 -> 0012/13
2/1   -> 0002/10
/18   -> 0000/18
45/   -> 0045/00
```

I.e. complete with leading zeros if it is the case for the first part before the "/" and with leading zeros if it is the case after the "/".

```cs
private void bt_showDataTable_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
    dataGridView2.DataSource = getDataTable();
}
    
public DataTable getDataTable()
{   
    DataTable dtTabla = new DataTable();
    try
    {
        MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection();
        connection.ConnectionString = configuracion.conexion;
        connection.Open();
    
        string query = "SELECT * FROM CC_T.CONSIGNATION WHERE ACCOUNT IN ('error');"; //query from the image above
    
        MySqlCommand mycmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
        mycmd.Connection = connection;
    
        MySqlDataReader reader = mycmd.ExecuteReader();
    
        dtTabla.Load(reader);

    }
    catch (MySqlException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
    
    return dtTabla;
}

// METHOD TO VALIDATE COURT CASE
public static bool Validar_Cc(string CourtCase)
{
    int i = 0;
    string part1 = "";
    string part2 = "";
    
    bool result1 = false;
    bool result2 = false;
    
    if (CourtCase.Contains("/"))
    {
        part1 = CourtCase.Substring(0, CourtCase.IndexOf('/'));
    
        part2 = CourtCase.Substring(CourtCase.IndexOf('/') + 1, CourtCase.Length - CourtCase.IndexOf('/') - 1);
    
        result1 = int.TryParse(part1, out i);
        result2 = int.TryParse(part2, out i);
    }
    
    if (!result1 || !result2)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else return true;
}
```

with this validation I only check that what comes for court_case is of type integer. but I do not check a validation of the format like: "**XXXX/XX**".

here I have to pass the method to validate:

```cs
private void btnCORRECT_ERROR_COURTCASE_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string reply = "";
    foreach(DataColumn column in dataGridView2.Rows)
    {
                //
    }
}
```

I know this is wrong but I don't know how to continue. Any help??

Comment: *the expected format would be: XX/XXXXXX ("4 digits" / "2 digits" )* - but.. xx/xxxxxx looks like "2 digits followed by slash followed by 6 digits".. Could you be a little more precise when forming questions, please?

Comment: Please explain the inconsistency in `12/13 -> 0012/113` - 113 is not 2 two digits

Comment: `12/13 -> 0012/113` implies a conversion, but most of your post seems to be talking about a check. Do you want to write code that formats the court case column to `xxxx/xx` or merely detects those that are not in format `xxxx/xx`?

Comment: sorry!! It is already modified

Comment: What would be the expected output for the second to last example data... `2/2008`?

Comment: would be to leave the last two numbers: 0002/08

Comment: Sorry but it seems that we still have some confusion. Do you want to check if the input values are in the correct format (xxxx/xx) or do you want to read and transform the inputs in the expected format? The answers so far are showing how to transform the input, not how to check if the input has the expected format

Comment: You've titled your question "**Modifying and** validating" - then you said *sorry!! It is already modified*, then you said you wanted `2/2008` modifying to `0002/08` . **Please decide what you actually want**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well technically you want to split the string to 2 parts, handle each separately and add it together with added zeroes. Like:

```cs
var inputArray = new string[4] { "12/13", "2/1", "/18", "45/" };
var results = new List<string>();

foreach (var str in inputArray)
{
    var parts = str.Split(new string[] { "/" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

    var result = parts[0].PadLeft(4, '0') + "/" + parts[1].PadLeft(2, '0');
    results.Add(result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `string.PadLeft` method to append leading zeros `0` (or other char) to some string:

```
static string AddLeadingZeros(string s, int amount)
{
    return s.PadLeft(amount, '0');
}
```

Usage example:

```
void FixCourtCases()
{
    string[] courtCases = new string[] 
    {
        "6906/2",
        "9163/2",
        "504/",
        "3/",
        "9/4",
        "4311/",
        "0/",
        "/6",
        "193/0",
        "0/2",
    };

    for (int i = 0; i < courtCases.Length; i++)
    {
         // Split left and right numbers by '/'
        string[] courtCase = courtCases[i].Split(new string[] { "/" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

        // Add leading zeros to left and right numbers
        string fixedLeftNumber = AddLeadingZeros(courtCase[0], 4);
        string fixedRightNumber = AddLeadingZeros(courtCase[1], 2)

        // Reassign value with fixed one
        courtCases[i] = fixedLeftNumber + "/" + fixedRightNumber;
    }
}
```

it will give you that kind of result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to check if the input (CourtCase) has the expected format (xxxx/xx) then you could change the **Validar_Cc** in this way.

```
public static bool Validar_Cc(string CourtCase)
{
    // First check, the string should be 7 character long, if not then fast exit
    if (CourtCase.Length != 7)
       return false;

    // Second check, try to split at /, if you get back an array with more or
    // less than two elements then fast exit
    string[] parts = CourtCase.Split('/');
    if(parts.Length != 2)
       return false;

    // Now check if the two elements are numbers or not. 
    // Again fast exit in case of error
    if(!Int32.TryParse(parts[0], out int number1))
       return false;
    if(!Int32.TryParse(parts[1], out int number2))
       return false;

    // If you reach this point then the data is correct
    return true;
}
```

This example assumes that you consider correct inputs like '0000/00' or '1234/00' or '0000/88'. If this is not the case then one more checks is needed. Just add these lines after the TryParse block

```
if(number1 == 0 || number2 == 0)
    return false;
```

And you could call the Validar_CC inside the loop over the grid rows

```
private void btnCORRECT_ERROR_COURTCASE_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string reply = "";
    foreach(DataGridRow row in dataGridView2.Rows)
    {
       bool result = Validar_Cc(row.Cells["COURT_CASE"].Value.ToString());
       .... do whatever you need to do with false/true results
    }
}
```

Comment: Sooo.. Why not just `return Regex.IsMatch(courtCase, @"\d{4}/\d\d)`?

Comment: We should really enumerate the DataTable, not the grid.. `Validar_Cc(row["COURT_CASE"] as string)`

Comment: Well, yes, a regex could be optimal here, just not thought about it. For the second comment, I really don't know what the OP wants to do after validating the input. Perhaps they need to just change some colors on the cell/row or add some visual clues on invalid rows. In that case it would be handy to work directly on the rows.